# I want to make setmousecallback function to pass the coordinate continuously when mouse left button is still pressed

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mouseevent

My code works fine but it is not continuously pass the co-ordinates when the left button of mouse is still pressed. It does pass the co-ordinates when mouse is moving.

Sorry i didn't add the mouse_callback function, I now have added that.
Any help would be helpful.
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point pt(-1, -1);
bool newCoords = false;
void mouse_callback(int  event, int  x, int  y, int  flag, void *param)
{
if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
{
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    newCoords = true;
}
else if (flag == EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON && event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE) {
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    newCoords = true;
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    String WindowName = "Original Feed";
    namedWindow(WindowName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Mat oriImg;
    int Frame_Width = 720;
    int Frame_Height = 540;

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    setMouseCallback(WindowName, mouse_callback);

    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, Frame_Width);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, Frame_Height);

    while (waitKey(30) != 27) {
        cap.read(oriImg);
        if (pt.x != -1 && pt.y != -1)
        {
            circle(oriImg, pt, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

            if (newCoords)
            {
                std::cout << "Clicked coordinates: " << pt << std::endl;
                newCoords = false;
            }
        }

        imshow(WindowName, oriImg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `newCoords` initialized elsewhere? I am guessing assigning `newCoords = true` on leftMousePress will solve your problem.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] -- right now `pt` is underfine and the entire implementation of `mouse_callback` is missing.

Comment: Hey @DanMašek, I have filled the blank, any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Hey @bruglesco, assigning newCoords = true on leftMousePress is not working. Any better idea?

Comment: If the state of the mouse (buttons, wheel, position) doesn't change, the callback won't be called (it gets called when the message loop receives relevant mouse events from the GUI, and the GUI won't generate them when nothing changes -- it's simply unnecessary). | What is it you actually want to achieve? As long as the button is held, draw the circle at the position of the cursor on every frame displayed?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YuVkj49G -- does that do what you want?

Comment: Hey @DanMašek, the code you provided works same as mine, what i want is when LBUTTONDOWN event occurs it should keep printing the position of mouse.

Comment: No, it doesn't work the same, for example yours will keep drawing a circle even when the button is not held down. I assumed the key part was drawing the circles correctly... if you also want to print, then just add a `std::cout << "Current position: " << ms.position << "\n";` just after the calls to `cv::circle`.

Comment: Hi @DanMašek, Thanks a lot, I finally got it what i was looking for. So again thank you so much. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is called whenever the OS/GUI generates a mouse event. Such events are generated whenever the state of the mouse (button, wheel, position, etc.) change -- if nothing changes, you already know (are can know) the current state.

If you want to somehow respond to a stable state of the mouse (e.g. button held down while stationary) in multiple iterations, you will have to handle it yourself.

---

The way I understand your problem is as follows: As long as the left button is held, draw the circle at the most recent position of the cursor on every frame displayed.

Since we're running at a decent frame rate, we can afford to keep things simple, and only update the current frame based on the click/position information from the previous frame. The user will not be able to observe this slight delay.

Just for posterity: the image is being displayed, and the mouse callback called only while the `cv::waitKey` function is running.

---

The following enumerates the situations we may encounter in each iteration and how we should react to them in the following frame:

1. LMB was not held at entry and exit of `waitKey`

   - LMB was never released (therefore never pressed) -> nothing to do
   - LMB was held and released at least once (and therefore pressed as many times) -> draw circle at position of last depress
2. LMB was not held at entry, but held at exit of `waitKey`

   - LMB is held down -> draw circle at last reported mouse position
3. LMB was held at entry, but not held at exit of `waitKey`

   - LMB was held and released at least once (and pressed one less time) -> draw circle at position of last depress
4. LMB was held at entry and exit of `waitKey`

   - LMB is held down -> draw circle at last reported mouse position

Based on this, we need to keep track of:

- The last position where the LMB was either held down, or released.
- Whether the LMB is currently being held down
- Whether the LMB was released in the previous iteration (i.e. it was held down, even though it no longer is)

We can use a `struct` to hold this info (which we let the callback use thanks to the user data parameter):

```
struct mouse_state
{
    mouse_state()
        : position(-1, -1)
        , left_button_held(false)
        , left_button_clicked(false)
    {}

    void new_iteration()
    {
        left_button_clicked = false;
    }

    cv::Point2i position; // Last position where the LMB was down
    bool left_button_held; // Is the LMB down right now?
    bool left_button_clicked; // Was the LMB down in the last iteration?
};
```

The mouse callback will be responsible for updating the above `struct`.

- When user presses LMB, record position and set button held
- When user releases LMB, record position, set button clicked, and set button not held
- When mouse moves and LMB held, record position

Sample implementation of the callback with some primitive debug tracing could look as such:

```
void mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param)
{
    mouse_state* state(static_cast<mouse_state*>(param));

    if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::cout << "LMB down @ (" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
        state->position = cv::Point2i(x, y);
        state->left_button_held = true;
    } else if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONUP) {
        std::cout << "LMB up @(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
        state->position = cv::Point2i(x, y);
        state->left_button_held = false;
        state->left_button_clicked = true;
    } else if ((flag == cv::EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON) && (event == cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)) {
        std::cout << "LMB held, mouse moved to (" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
        state->position = cv::Point2i(x, y);
    }
}
```

The callback then could be registered in the following manner:

```
mouse_state ms;
cv::setMouseCallback(WINDOW_NAME, mouse_callback, &ms);
```

The processing loop would then be quite simple:

1. Read new frame, exit loop on failure
2. Check last mouse state. If LMB is held, or was clicked, draw circle at recorded position.
3. Reset per-iteration mouse state flags
4. Show image, update mouse state info

This might look as follows:

```
for (;;) {
    // We can have `image` here, since `cap.read` always gives us
    // a reference to its internal buffer
    cv::Mat image;
    if (!cap.read(image)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read image, exiting...\n";
        break; // Failed to read image, nothing else to do
    }

    if (ms.left_button_clicked || ms.left_button_held) {
        std::cout << "Current position: " << ms.position << "\n";
        cv::circle(image, ms.position, 3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        cv::circle(image, ms.position, 10, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    ms.new_iteration();

    cv::imshow(WINDOW_NAME, image);
    if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) {
        std::cout << "Esc pressed, exiting...\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

---

### Sample Program

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct mouse_state
{
    mouse_state()
        : position(-1, -1)
        , left_button_held(false)
        , left_button_clicked(false)
    {}

    void new_iteration()
    {
        left_button_clicked = false;
    }

    cv::Point2i position; // Last position where the LMB was down
    bool left_button_held; // Is the LMB down right now?
    bool left_button_clicked; // Was the LMB down in the last iteration?
};

void mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param)
{
    mouse_state* state(static_cast<mouse_state*>(param));

    if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::cout << "LMB down @ (" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
        state->position = cv::Point2i(x, y);
        state->left_button_held = true;
    } else if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONUP) {
        std::cout << "LMB up @(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
        state->position = cv::Point2i(x, y);
        state->left_button_held = false;
        state->left_button_clicked = true;
    } else if ((flag == cv::EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON) && (event == cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)) {
        std::cout << "LMB held, mouse moved to (" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
        state->position = cv::Point2i(x, y);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::String const WINDOW_NAME("Original Feed");
    cv::namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    mouse_state ms;
    cv::setMouseCallback(WINDOW_NAME, mouse_callback, &ms);

    int const FRAME_WIDTH(720);
    int const FRAME_HEIGHT(540);

    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open camera, exiting...\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);

    for (;;) {
        // We can have `image` here, since `cap.read` always gives us
        // a reference to its internal buffer
        cv::Mat image;
        if (!cap.read(image)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read image, exiting...\n";
            break; // Failed to read image, nothing else to do
        }

        if (ms.left_button_clicked || ms.left_button_held) {
            std::cout << "Current position: " << ms.position << "\n";
            cv::circle(image, ms.position, 3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            cv::circle(image, ms.position, 10, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        }

        ms.new_iteration();

        cv::imshow(WINDOW_NAME, image);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) {
            std::cout << "Esc pressed, exiting...\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```